# Cannot get internal XAML binding to work against a Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, data-binding

I have a user control "CtrlComments", this control has the following XAML (It's super basic).

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:wpftoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
x:Name="ucRoot">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="ID: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Deployment.Id}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The code behind is as follows, it's the bare basics to get the control to function. The key is the DependencyObject typeof(DeploymentDto) which has an `int` property called `Id` that we are interested in showing on our window as per XAML binding above.

```
public partial class CtrlComments : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeploymentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Deployment", typeof(DeploymentDto),
                                    typeof(CtrlComments), new PropertyMetadata(new DeploymentDto()));

    public DeploymentDto Deployment
    {
        get
        {
            return (DeploymentDto)GetValue(DeploymentProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DeploymentProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Deployment"));
        }
    }

    public CtrlComments()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Our problem is, despite the fact that the binding between the parent control and my user control via the dependency property is working (verified) and the `OnPropertyChanged` method firing, the `TextBlock` in my XAML isn't updating.

I have noticed that when the `OnPropertyChanged` method is run, the eventhandler is `null` meaning no one is notified that there was a property change.

I don't understand why this is the case though. If you could help explain where we are going wrong it would be enormously appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: OnPropertyChange does not check if your DP is working and in fact it is not. The types you pass into your DependencyProperty are wrong.

Comment: Try `public static readonly DependencyProperty DeploymentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Deployment", typeof(DeploymentDto),
                                    typeof(CtrlComments), new PropertyMetadata(new DeploymentDto()));`

Comment: Yes sorry, the types in our code are correct, was a transcribing typo into the question. We are using the same as you recommended.
We are able to verify the dependency object being bound correctly by observing the set operation/s using a break point and we are satisfied that it is working correctly.

Comment: if you are setting by Xaml binding, then it should not be hitting your setter.

Comment: I think you are confusing the internal xaml (displayed in the question, which is not setting) and the xaml of the intended parent control for the CtrlComments control (not displayed), which is data bound to Deployment and does hit the setter.

Comment: Try this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Deployment.Id ElementName=ucRoot}" />`

Comment: @XavierHutchinson It's not the cause of your problem here, but it's probably worth pointing out that in a dependency property getter you should only call `GetValue` and in the setter you should only call `SetValue`. [There should be no additional code](http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/11/07/118-dont-add-code-to-dependency-property-gettersetter/) other than these two calls. This is because in binding scenarios WPF will not call your CLR property getter/setter and you don't want a difference in behaviour between the CLR property and the dependency property.

Comment: @XavierHutchinson Did you solve the problem in the meantime, or does it still persist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to replicate your problem and while doing so, I figured that the problem for me was in the following line in `CtrlComments`:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Dropping this line just made it work for me. Also note (as @Aron wrote in the comments) that the `OnPropertyChanged` of `INotifyPropertyChanged` shouldn't be called while in the setter of the `DependencyProperty`. At least for me it isn't necessary to implement INPC at all.

In the XAML file where you are using the UserControl you are most likely going to have another `DataContext` set (on a higher level, perhaps in the `Window`), and thus I guess it isn't inherited to the user control if already set in there (or overwritten). Below is my working code, but perhaps I misunderstood exactly what you're doing. If that is the case, please extend your question to include how you are using the UserControl, as that is a key to answering the question if this doesn't work :)

CtrlComments.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.CtrlComments"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="ID: "/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Deployment.Id}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CtrlComments.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class CtrlComments : UserControl
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeploymentProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Deployment", typeof(DeploymentDto), typeof(CtrlComments), new PropertyMetadata(new DeploymentDto { Id = 5 }));

    public DeploymentDto Deployment
    {
      get { return (DeploymentDto)GetValue(DeploymentProperty); }
      set
      {
        SetValue(DeploymentProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public CtrlComments()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <StackPanel>
    <local:CtrlComments x:Name="testUC" Height="100" Deployment="{Binding Deployment}"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="50" Width="100"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private DeploymentDto deployment = new DeploymentDto { Id = 2 };
    public DeploymentDto Deployment
    {
      get { return deployment; }
      set { deployment = value; OnPropertyChanged("Deployment"); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Deployment = new DeploymentDto { Id = new Random().Next(100) };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DeploymentDto:

```
public class DeploymentDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

It's quite ugly to bind `MainWindow.DataContext` to its code-behind, but since it's just used for example purposes I hope it's okay :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you don't need this.DataContext = this; at all. You can give your UserControl an x:Name and your binding can reference the ElementName.